# UK online visa application: travelling "with" someone who doesn't have visa "yet"

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork

I am filling in the UK online visa application on visa4uk.gov.uk. They ask if I am travelling "with" anyone. My plans have been made in conjunction with someone else, we arrive at the same time and leave at the same time and some of our tickets have both our names on them although our movements will differ some of the time, and we are doing separate interviews. I would like to give them every detail possible to as not to be accused of withholding information.

However there is this question about "does this person have a valid visa for the UK?". The answer is "not yet", he will not have a visa until his own application process is complete (just like me). However the options are "yes" and "no". So the correct answer is (currently) "no". Will this cause my own application hassles?

Comment: Is this visiting the UK, or moving there?

Comment: Visiting for a holiday

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In general, they are trying to find out if, for example, a child is travelling with their parent or if a person is travelling with their spouse.   Also they are trying to establish the person's premise for visiting the UK and sometimes if a person is travelling with a group the info can be useful.  Finally, the info is helpful in understanding the applicant's connection to the UK (if there is one) and if their visit is contingent on another person getting a visa.

Based upon what you wrote, you are travelling with a friend/companion.  You would answer the question honestly and check the 'NO' box if the person does not have a valid UK visa.

Optionally, you can then go to Part 9 of the form and enter a brief explanation of how and when your friend/companion will apply for their visa.  In fact you can simply reword your text above (i.e., your question) and copy it to Part 9.  It is OK to be explicit about your relationship with your friend/companion because it helps establish the premise of both your visits.