# UK Visa application: "Travelling with another person"?

Tags: visas, uk

I'm filling out my Tier 4 UK visa application for postgraduate studies and will be travelling with my parents to the UK a week before my program starts for a little vacation. My parents will only be with me for a week, but do I still need to list them on the "travelling with another person" section in the application?

Comment: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45283/uk-online-visa-application-travelling-with-someone-who-doesnt-have-visa-yet?rq=1